# Can I request a webpage with JavaScript and then send it as is to a server to be analyzed further?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

what I'm trying to achieve is to call a webpage with JavaScript get the HTML and send it to a server to be further analyzed.

Is it even possible? Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequest to GET a page and POST it to a backend URL address.

However, you'll be limited to same-origin policy, i.e, the URL of the page you GET and the URL of the POST to receive the data must both be of same origin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

There are workarounds, depending on your application needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, After your comment I realized I needed to phrased the question differently. What I'm trying to do Is to use a chrome extension to get a page content and send it to a server to be processed. (Can't use the server to send the request, the requirement is that the request comes from the chrome extension and passed along), Do you know what would be a good way to go about it?

Comment: yes, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr for specifics of same_origin for extensions

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for AJAX. It can send httpRequests on client side or please tell what do you exactly need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, After your comment I realized I needed to phrased the question differently. What I'm trying to do Is to use a chrome extension to get a page content and send it to a server to be processed. (Can't use the server to send the request, the requirement is that the request comes from the chrome extension and passed along), would AJAX still fit the bill?

Comment: So AJAX will do it without refreshing page. You can display content with AJAX. Chrome sends data to your server and you display content without refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

using Javascript to crawl the web ? bad idea : you can make it directly in your back-end